# Pyspark is dorping my columns with Null values on write

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have a problem regarding Pyspark writing, I'm currently running the following line:

```
sat_prospect_credentials.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(f"{TABLE_MAP[table]}")
```

Which is writing a Spark DataFrame to an Azure ADLS in delta format. I have the following issue, I have a column called end_date which is filled with Null values (this is on purpose as this is for SCD management), however, when I write to DataLake, that column is being dropped. Does anyone know hot to prevent this?
[image: This is the original DataFrame with the end_date column]

[image: After writing without the column]

Thanks!

I've tried schemaOverwrite, mergeSchema and other options. I have no idea how to follow-up from here onwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delta Lake uses Parquet as a data storage format, and it doesn't have support for columns with null type, so the columns with the null type are dropped - that's a well known issue, you can read about it in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/450).

If you want to preserve null values, you need to cast them to a some type, for example, to `string` (or in your case to `date`), so the column won't have a null type. Something like this:

```py
df = df.withColumn("end_date", col("end_date").cast("date"))
```